# how can i fix laggy parallex scrolling on safari and firefox?

Tags: html, css

i made a project but found the parallax scrolling was chipping and was not as smooth as on chrome. at the moment I'm also creating a website for professional purposes so wanted to fix this. thanks in advance

```css
#content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
                 0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496046744122-2328018d60b6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1528&q=80");
      min-height: 850px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax {
background-color: white;

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 665px; 

 }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Holidays 4 You</h1>
                <h3> The Best Holiday Finder Out There</h3>
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><a href="form.html">Get Started!</a></button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="parallax">
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the Images on your website are JPG maybe they are to big and thats what makes preformance issue try useing SVG or PNG